# Is QGIS aspect analysis description mistaken?

Tags: qgis, raster, aspect

I've been checking the Aspect analysis tool and several sources indicate that aspect is measured from 0 to 360, starting North and going counter-clockwise. Nevertheless, I've been testing it on several regions, some of which I know quite well and the measurement is actually being done clockwise.

Am I right? Are the descriptions and tutorials that state the direction as being counterclockwise mistaken?

Comment: if you use the default GDAL Aspect tool settings, it should be clockwise from North - although if you use the trigonometric option it's anti-clockwise from East, which should match r.slope.aspect behaviour